How to prevent refetch on component unmount
In my react app, I have a Chat page. In this page, I have a query to fetch conversations.
  const {
    data: conversations,
    isLoading: isConversationsLoading,
    error: conversationFetchError,
  } = useFetchData(["getConversations"], `/conversation/${user._id}`, {
    refetchInterval: 1000 * 60 * 5, // refetch sidebar data every 5 minutes so that timestamp updates
  });

The implementation of useFetchData:
const useFetchData = (queryKey, url, options = {}) => {
  const { logoutActions } = useAuthContext();
  const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery({
    queryKey,
    queryFn: () => axiosInstance.get(url),
    ...options,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
        toast.error(error.response.data.message);
        logoutActions();
      }
    }
  }, [error, logoutActions]);

  return { isLoading, error, data };
};

When I logout, the user state in AuthContext is set to null. Thus, my app redirects to the login page. My logout function in Navbar component:
const mutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: () => {
      return axiosInstance.post("/auth/logout", {});
    },
    onSuccess: (response) => {
      toast.success(response.data.message);
      logoutActions();
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      toast.error(
        error.response ? error.response.data.message : "Something went wrong"
      );
    },
  });

logoutActions() resides in AuthContext. The implementation of logoutActions():
const logoutActions = () => {
    if (socket) {
      socket.disconnect();
      setSocket(null);
    }
    setUser(null);
    resetConversations();
    resetGroups();
    queryClient.cancelQueries();
    queryClient.removeQueries();
  };

When calling queryClient.cancelQueries(); and queryClient.removeQueries();, it refetches the getConversations query that I implemented in the Chat.jsx. How to stop re-fetching the query since I get an error, because the token has already been invalidated? I just want to remove the query. Actually all the queries of my app.

Hello, what does the resetGroups() and resetConversations() function do? Can you check is your logoutActions generate some re-rendering on Chat Page ?

Those two functions set the states to the initial state. Basically, set null.
`const initialStates = {
selectedGroup: null,
};
const groupStore = create((set) => ({
...initialStates,
setSelectedGroup: (state) => set({ selectedGroup: state }),
resetGroups: () => set(initialStates),
}));
`
I removed those functions. But no luck.

Okay and is your logoutActions generate some re-rendering on Chat Page ?
